# Чи існує слово "цимбалоїд"?

Tags: значення-слів

Вчора почув розмову, де один зі співрозмовник назвав іншого *цимбалоїдом*. Я спитав про значення слова. Вони мені пояснили, що це людина якій все байдуже, тобто по цимбалах. Чи є таке слово?

Comment: В широкому сенсі, під час лайки люди досить часто використовують неологізми, це будь-якої мови і культури стосується… У цьому контексті, чи не могли б ви уточнити значення запитання «чи є таке слово»? Де воно є? У словниках? — то може і не бути.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Словник синонїмів](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53414/275543.html) ([Святослав Караванський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87))

> **Цимбал**
>   Дурбило, йoлоп, телепень; *мн.* [цимбали](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96)), *(музичний инструмент)* цимбалики.

Инші словники мають схожі значення.

[-*оїд*](http://www.z-school.man.gov.ua/assets/files/lingvistychna_shkola/ukrmova/samostijna/2015/12/l_4_morfemika.pdf) — узвичаєний афіксоїд давньогелладського походження зї значенням: *подїбний до*, *форма*, рідше *ідея*.

Якщо по-нашому: *цимбалоподїбний*. Отже слово цїлком може існувати, трактувати можна як *подїбний до форми музичного инструменту*, або як *(подоба) до дурної істоти*.